# Total Variation Distance(between Gaussians)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distance

I am interested in a tool that calculates the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between two multivariate Normal distributions. Any help will be much appreciated as I am a complete beginner.(So far, I have searched for this tool in any programming language I know and to my surprise I haven't found anything. I am also not so sure that the tool that I have built is accurate.)

Comment: Do you have Mathematica? Am I right in saying the total variation distance is the maximum of the absolute difference between the CDFs of the distributions? In which case it would be `NMaximize[Abs[CDF[d1, x] - CDF[d2, x]], x]` in Mathematica for given distributions `d1, d2`

Comment: You got me. I don't actually have it. (I hope that doesn't mean that I can't post the question). I am looking where I can implement it first before installing a bunch of programs that may end up useless. Can you explain what $x$ is in your type?

Comment: `x` is just the variable that appears in the cumulative density functions of your normal distributions. Since Mathematica is not free you may want to look into R instead which has a package distrEx and this https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/distrEx/versions/2.8.0/topics/TotalVarDist .

Comment: ^ oh yeah that's 1D only and you asked about multivariate. In Mathematica for 2D that would be `NMaximize[Abs[CDF[d1, {x,y}] - CDF[d2, {x,y}]], {x,y}]` and d1 and d2 would be `MultinormalDistribution`s, assuming that's the correct definition for TVD.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure that's correct. It may be it's just that I don't know about it.